# scraping facebook pages data

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

is this possible to scrape Facebook pages data in scv file including Map location, Facebook URL category, Tags, Description Logo & Facebook Cover image URLs.

is this possible ?

Kindly reply as soon as possible

Comment: why down ?????????

Comment: first of all, scraping is not allowed on facebook, you MUST use the graph api. also, you are required to add what you have tried so far on stackoverflow (research, code, debug info, ...)

Comment: i use the graph api .. but some fields not available like these Postcode, Map location, Facebook URL category, Tags, Description Logo & Facebook Cover image URLs ??

Comment: rule of thumb: if it is not available with the graph api, there is no (allowed) way.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah you can, use tools like [selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org/), [pupeteer](https://pptr.dev/). As facebook is built with reactjs, you can easily **scrape** like normal traditional websites. These tools make this possible to **scrape** these websites.

Comment: what about power bi ? in power bi is this possible ?